# android: how to stop slide in-slideout in new activity on android API 7?

Tags: android

In andriod API 7 it is automatic `slide_in_left` and `slide_out_right` Animation in actvity. so i dont need to do this in each and every activity so how can i stop this animation and how can i animate normally?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may set other animation using overridePendingTransition() just after calling startActivity() or finish() [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29)